# ¿Cómo incluir barra invertida como carácter de String en C#?

Tags: c#

tengo el siguiente problema y deseo que me puedan ayudar ya que no logro darle una solución:

Me dan unas credenciales para conectarme a un SFTP pero el usuario contiene una barra invertida: `app-exigofiles-prod-global\$app-exigofiles-prod-global`.

Desarrollé un programa en C# para acceder al SFTP pero me marca error, deseo que C# reconosca el nombre de usuario como string incluida la barra invertida, es posible alguna solución para que no me marque error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta ponerle doble barra invertida `..global\\$app..`

Comment: Código como texto, porfa

Comment: Lo intenté, elimina el error pero el usuario es solo con una barra invertida asi que manda otro error a la hora de acceder al sftp.

Answer (score 2):

Opción 1: utilizas caracter de escape y te queda así:

```
string cuenta = "dominio\\usuario";
```

Opción 2: (recomendada) utilizas el "verbatin string literal"

```
string cuenta = @"dominio\usuario";
```

referencia: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/

Comment: Ya intenté de las 2 formas pero ninguna me sirve.

Comment: Pero sigue siendo el mismo error que marcas en la imagen?, porque la descripción de error creo que está solventada, si te sale otro tipo de error pues podrías intentar hacer alguna búsqueda o realizar otra pregunta con el nuevo error. Saludos.

Comment: la pregunta es ¿Cómo incluir barra invertida como carácter de String en C#?, aún no logro solucionarlo.

Comment: Cuando me refiero al error quiero decir al mensaje que te da al momento de asignar el valor en cadena, lo cual es evidentemente incorrecta, al hacerlo de esa forma te dice "secuencia de escape no reconocida", al aplicar lo que te han propuesto el error se solventa, deduzco que estás obteniendo es otro error de autenticación, lo cual no se con certeza porque no está formulada en la pregunta.

Comment: No puedo utilizar 2 barras invertidas porque el usuario solo tiene una barra invertida.

Comment: @Guillermo no son 2 barras invertidas. En el código fuente necesitas escribir 2, pero representan un solo caracter. Mírate la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char#literals). https://tio.run/##jY4xC8IwEIX3/IrDpe2gaDuWDuKqIHRwsA4hxhqoCeSiKKW/vSa1rQq1eEPI8b337jGcMqV5XV9RyBzSBxp@iQkrKCJstco1vhttps://tio.run/##HYuxCoNAEAX7@4rXqUXyA5apA4EUKWKK5TyOBb2F3U1AxG@/qNPOTLRLFE21fo1LxnMxT3Mf4kRmeKhkpRlrwI45OUf8hEfciUtrrvvz/oA0W4cVZ3Zwk2IypetL2VPbDEPT9afcwlbrHw

Comment: También pensé lo mismo pero a la hora de acceder al sftp lo reconoce como doble barra invertida

Comment: @Guillermo no tiene sentido. La pregunta ya está respondida. Eso forma parte de otro problema. Si escribes `@"\\"` si habrán 2 barras.

Comment: Si usas el verbatin string literal a arroba (@) antes de la cadena solo escribes una sola diagonal y solo una aparecerá, en todo caso podrías actualizar con captura de la inspección de variables para ver como va